# mega dropdown will not go full width but stays within the container of the <li> that triggered

Tags: html, css

i'm using twitter bootstrap and wish to have a number of drop-down sub menus. Problem is I want my 'mega-dropdown-menu' to be 100% width of the page yet all the others need to remain at 180px. Currently the mega-dropdown menu is either confined by the width of the `<li>` element that triggers it OR the default width used by all the normal dropdown-menus (180px).

I have tried using !important on the 'mega-dropdown menu' class. I have also tried removing a width and setting *left* and *right* to 'auto'. When i just use 100% it is contained by the parent `<li>`

I'd also like to make the arrow appear to point at the `<li>` that triggered the mega-dropdown menu.

```
.container {
    width:100% !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*START MEGA MENU CSS*/

.dropdown-menu {

width: 150px !important;
background: #45484d; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6-15 
*/
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.dropdown-header1 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    color: #F58220 !important;
    padding-left: 17px !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown {
  position: relative !important;
  width: 180px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 1000px !important;
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
  overflow:visible;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  background-color:#000000;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #43464b;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #43464b;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu form {
  margin: 3px 20px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.divider {
    border-bottom:dotted 1px #ccc !important;
}
```

The HTML is pretty standard as you can see too:

I'd be grateful for any input on this as its driving me nuts!! Quite happy to start again if my approach is way off to start with? Not overly concerned about how it is handled on mobile as I will be hiding the mega-menu on smaller devices and replacing with a vanilla 'dropdown-menu'.

```
       <!-- Navigation -->
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="header-container" class="container navbar-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a id="brand" class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="https://www.inciner8.com/images/full-logo-white.png" width="160" height="25"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
            <a href="#incinerators" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">INCINERATORS <b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Most Popular</li>
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=i8M-60+Medical" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                          <h4><small>Self-contained Medical Incinerator</small></h4>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">GET a Quote</button>
                          <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> more info...</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Item -->
                        <div class="item">
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=Large+Capacity" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                          <h4><small>Our Flagship 1 Tonne Incinerator</small></h4>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">GET a Quote</button>
                          <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> more info...</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Item -->
                        <div class="item">
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=Dual+Chamber" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                          <h4><small>Hot Hearth Designed Dual Chamber Pet Cremator</small></h4>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">GET a Quote</button>
                          <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> more info...</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Item -->
                      </div>
                      <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.carousel -->
                  </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </li>



            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PET CREMATION <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dual Chamber Pet Cremator <span class="badge badge-important pull-right">New!</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Horse Cremator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Heat Exchangers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pet Cremation Accessories</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">Want to learn more?</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Starting a Pet Crematorium</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pet Cremation Business Plan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pet Cremation Business Franchise</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WASTE TO ENERGY <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">EFW-40</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EFW-20</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Heat Exchangers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Organic Ranking Cycle Engine</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">Want to learn more?</li>
                        <li><a href="#">What is W2E?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Use Incinerators to Create Electricity</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">POLLUTION CONTROL <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Small PCS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Large PCS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Venturi Scrubber</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">Want to learn more?</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ceramic Filters</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activated Carbon Filters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lime Feed</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">What are Acceptable Emission Levels?</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">INCINERATION <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Types of Incinerator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">What you Can/Cannot Burn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Legislation</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">Want to Learn More?</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Read our Blog...</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SUPPORT <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Download Brochures & Datasheets <span class="badge badge-important pull-right">New!</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Emissions Quick Reference</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fuel Consumption Quick Reference</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dealer Resources</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">Useful Resources</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Visit our <strong>spare parts website</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activate your Warranty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Become a Dealer</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Become a Dealer</a></li>     
                        <li class="divider"></li>    
                        <li class="dropdown-header1">FREE Waste Audit Templates <span class="badge badge-important pull-right">New!</span></li>    
                        <li><a href="#">Waste Audit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Waste Logbook</a></li>   
                        <li><a href="#">Medical Waste Logbook</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Animal Waste Logbook</a></li>    
                      </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Company History</a> <span class="badge badge-important pull-right">New!</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Awards & Accreditations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Values</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </li>



            <li><a href="#contact" class="btn-primary" type="button">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: Can you use 100vw instead of 100%? This should make it the full width of the viewport, if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: just tried that and made no difference. I notice that the parent has a width that has '!important' on it that seems to then override the 100vw that I put in the mega-dropdown menu class. 

You can see a example of it here: [https://www.inciner8.com/childtest.php]

Comment: Yes, there's an !important rule on .dropdown-menu, you will need to make your override style more specific by also adding !important to it.

Comment: i'm already using !important - problem is its being ignored.